# Microsoft Azure (Automation): Runbook passing Hash as Parameter

Tags: powershell, azure, hash, parameters

I'm trying to pass a hash like `{"server":"database","server2":"database_b"}` as a parameter to a runbook on Microsoft Azure. But neither

`[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  [hashtable]$ServersWithCorrespondingDatabase,`

nor

`[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  [object]$ServersWithCorrespondingDatabase,`

seems to work?

In this example [Runbook Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Start-Azure-Automation-1ac858a9) they go with the argument `ChildRunbookInputParams` as hashtable, like:

```
Start-ChildRunbook ` 
    -ChildRunbookName "Update-VM" ` 
    -ChildRunbookInputParams @{'VMName'='VM204';'Retries'=3} ` 
    -AzureConnectionName "Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN" 
    -AutomationAccountName "Contoso IT Automation Production" ` 
    -WaitForJobCompletion $true ` 
    -ReturnJobOutput $true ` 
    -JobPollingIntervalInSeconds 20 ` 
    -JobPollingTimeoutInSeconds 120
```

But somehow I can not pass the string `@{"Server"="DB";"Server2"="DB3"}` to my azure runbook as a parameter... Any idea?

Comment: You should probably specify that the question is related to Azure Automation.

Comment: I thought it would be clear by writing microsoft azure together with runbook. Added it for completeness. 10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the runbook, you should define the parameter as [object] type, not [hashtable]. Are you starting the runbook through the Azure Automation portal, or inline via another runbook?

Assuming this is your runbook:

```
workflow a {
    param(
       [object] $obj
    )

    $obj
}
```

If via the portal, you need to specify the object parameter as JSON, ex:

```
{"server":"database","server2":"database_b"}
```

If via a runbook calling this runbook inline, specify it as a PowerShell object or hashtable:

```
a -Obj @{"server"="database";"server2"="database_b"}
```

For more info see http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/12/azure-automation-runbook-input-output-and-nested-runbooks/

Edit: If you are trying to start this runbook specifically by calling the Start-ChildRunbook runbook within a runbook, it would look like this, since the Start-ChildRunbook runbook takes the parameters of the runbook to start as a hashtable, and in this case the value of one of those parameters is a hashtable/object itself:

```
$ValueForObjParam = @{"server"="database";"server2"="database_b"}

Start-ChildRunbook ` 
    -ChildRunbookName "a" ` 
    -ChildRunbookInputParams @{"obj"=$ValueForObjParam} ` 
    -AzureConnectionName "Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN" `
    -AutomationAccountName "Contoso IT Automation Production" ` 
    -WaitForJobCompletion $true ` 
    -ReturnJobOutput $true ` 
    -JobPollingIntervalInSeconds 20 ` 
    -JobPollingTimeoutInSeconds 120
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you refer to in the gallery uses a hashtable to specify all the params to the child runbook, not a single param of type hashtable. So, the child runbook probably has a param block like so:

```
workflow start-update-vm
{
param ($VMName, $retries)
#rest of code
}
```

You can, however, take a stringed json input and it will be converted into a hashtable/array as described here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/orchestrator/archive/2014/01/10/sma-capabilities-in-depth-runbook-input-output-and-nested-runbooks.aspx.

Comment: ?

The script I refer is: Start-ChildRunbook, which takes a hashtable as Argument. 

`.PARAMETER ChildRunbookInputParams 
    A hashtable with the names of parameters of the runbook to start as keys and values for these parameters as values`

and gives it to the child runbook as params. I've also seen the link you mentioned, but for me it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. My point is that the hashtable is not ONE parameter, its a hashtable containing the parameters expected by the child runbook (which is called start-update-vm in the example).